# Reproject and Export: Data is not reprojected in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-python-api

Google Earth Engine Exporting via Python API a Sentinel 2 harmonized mosaic to the Swiss projection EPSG:2056 results in non correctly reprojected data.

Complete code https://code.earthengine.google.com/4639f0a4a102c553319a02bc8e17dc3f

Following the DOC data was reprojected:

```
var S2_mosaic_reprojected = S2_mosaic.reproject({
       crs:'EPSG:2056',
      scale: 10 })
```

and then exported

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S2_mosaic_reprojected,
  description: 'ProjectionAccordingToTheDOC',
  scale: 10,
  crs:'EPSG:2056',
  region: geometry
});
```

I get an image where each tile of the Geotiff is distorted.

See the highway as reference in the images below

**Distorted image EPSG 2056**

COGVIEWER: [Link](https://www.cogeo.org/map/#/url/https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fid%3D1diNuOc071C-9_mzbt03qO4mfmjCC4-xa/center/7.08824,46.11378/zoom/17)

Download: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1diNuOc071C-9_mzbt03qO4mfmjCC4-xa&export=download

**Non distorted image when exporting with Webmercator  EPSG:3857 (** no reprojection applied)

COGVIEWER: [Link](https://www.cogeo.org/map/#/url/https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fid%3D1lnc3Q1U0hYgb3DZdbG4Z8EZHIWYiGzZY/center/7.0863,46.1139/zoom/16)

Download: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1lnc3Q1U0hYgb3DZdbG4Z8EZHIWYiGzZY&export=download

I also defined the Projection manually according to Noels hint in https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/08lIYUCROyA/m/kYmzzxe4AAAJ - no luck so far . I posted the question as well in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/O4numBp53AM) but no feedback so far

Overall all goal: export the area of Switzerland approx 42k km2, reprojected.

What did I configure wrong in the code? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Not Solved even if RTFM: "The scale parameter can be subtly misleading. If you're trying to match an existing projection exactly, you shouldn't use scale - see the following section for details." as stated in the [Doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#setting_scale)

Therefore, determine first source projection

```
var projection = S2_mosaic.projection().getInfo();
```

and then exported

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S2_mosaic,
  description: 'ProjectionAccordingToTheDOC',
  region: geometry,
  crs:'EPSG:2056',
  crsTransform: projection.transform      
});
```

BUT The scale of the pixel is now 1m  instead of 10m...but at least projection  is " Better"

There is a confirmed Issue with export resulting in grid like artefacts

See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290641644

Answer (score 0):

There is a confirmed Issue with export resulting in grid like artefacts

See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290641644

and as well a visual overview of the issue in https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1H2y-ezhedk5N3Fm_96Vv4-PxLMOzeBV7Kq0MuhKOdok/edit?usp=sharing